# Vim keymaps in atom

Tags: atom-editor, key-bindings, keymapping

As far as I understand, there is no way to run .vimrc from atom in vim-mode-plus, but I can still use atoms way of binding keys using keymap.cson. How can I move the keys H-J-K-L one key right (J-K-L-Ø, since I have a Norwegian keyboard) using keymap.cson?

Comment: I don't think the VIM tag is appropriate here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add maps like this in keymap.cson:

```
'atom-text-editor.vim-mode-plus:not(.insert-mode)':
    'J': 'vim-mode-plus:move-left'
    'K': 'vim-mode-plus:move-down'
    'L': 'vim-mode-plus:move-up'
    'Ø': 'vim-mode-plus:move-right'
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! Btw the right part should be in a string though.

Comment: @KnutAndersStokke Wow, how did I miss that... fixed :)